# Slack message with button, a warning "This app has not been configured this feature"

Tags: slack

I use Slack API to post a message that has 2 buttons, looks like this one:

```
 {
    "type": "button",
    "text": {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "Edit Submission"
    },
    "url": shared_editor_link
}
```

The message post successfully and the button is working to open a link in browser.  However, a triangle warning sign pops beside the buttons after I clicked the button.  It has a hint message "This app has not been configured this feature, please contact the app's developer".  What does it mean?  I tried modify the permissions, add Link:Read, Link:Write, Remote_File:Read but no luck.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone reading this. My workaround was to enable interactivity for my app in the app management page (https://api.slack.com/apps/XXXXXXXXX > Interactivity & Shortcuts). Then set the Request URL to https://httpstat.us/200

It basically gives a `200 OK` response to any requests and it seems to keep my Slack app quiet

Answer (score 2):

Found this discussion, seems Slack needs to setup a response for link button:
https://github.com/slackapi/node-slack-sdk/issues/869